# How to add namespace prefix for IXmlSerializable type

Tags: xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, prefix, ixmlserializable

I have a following class definition

```c#
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "person",Namespace = "MyNamespace")]
public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces
    {
        get
        {
            var xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("My", "MyNamespace");
            return xmlSerializerNamespaces;
        }
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"/>
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("firstName",FirstName);
        writer.WriteElementString("lastName", LastName);
    }
}
```

an I want to serialize it with **My:** prefix for MyNamespace, so when I call code

```c#
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
var person = new Person
            { FirstName = "John",LastName = "Doe"};            
xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, person, person.Namespaces);
```

I expect following output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<My:person xmlns:My="MyNamespace">
    <My:firstName>John</My:firstName>
    <My:lastName>Doe</My:lastName>
</My:person>
```

But instead of it I am getting following output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<person xmlns="MyNamespace">
  <firstName>John</firstName>
  <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</person>
```

I know that writing prefixes works when I use **SerializableAttribute** attribute and not inherit from **IXmlSerializable**, but my class in the project is much more complex and I can't use default XmlSerializer.

Comment: Can you migrate your data to json?  It is a LOT easier.

Comment: @AndrewGray No, I can't. I am implementing WebDAV and it is not communicating in Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` type doesn't offer anything out-of-the-box to handle this.
If you really need to use `XmlSerializer`, you are going to end up with a custom `XmlSerializer` implementation, which isn't quite open to extend. For this reason the implementation below is more a proof of concept, just to give you an idea or a starting point.
For brevity I have omitted any error handling and only focussed on the `Person` class in your question. There's still some work to do to handle any nested complex properties.

As the `Serialize` methods are not `virtual` we'll have to shadow them. The main idea is to direct all overloads to a single one having the custom implementation.

Because of the customization, we'll have to be more explicit in the `Person` class when writing the xml elements for its properties by specifying the xml namespace to be applied.

The code below

```c#
PrefixedXmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new PrefixedXmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
Person person = new Person { 
    FirstName = "John", 
    LastName = "Doe" 
    };
xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, person, person.Namespaces);
```

results in

```xml
<My:person xmlns:My="MyNamespace">
    <My:firstName>John</My:firstName>
    <My:lastName>Doe</My:lastName>
</My:person>
```

It's up to you to consider whether this all is acceptable.
In the end, `<My:person xmlns:My="MyNamespace">` equals `<person xmlns="MyNamespace">`.

**Person**

```c#
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "person", Namespace = NAMESPACE)]
public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    private const string NAMESPACE = "MyNamespace";

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces
    {
        get
        {
            var xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("My", NAMESPACE);                
            return xmlSerializerNamespaces;
        }
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"/>
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }   

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // Specify the xml namespace.
        writer.WriteElementString("firstName", NAMESPACE, FirstName);
        writer.WriteElementString("lastName", NAMESPACE, LastName);
    }
}
```

**PrefixedXmlSerializer**

```c#
public class PrefixedXmlSerializer : XmlSerializer
{
    XmlRootAttribute _xmlRootAttribute;


    public PrefixedXmlSerializer(Type type) : base(type)
    {
        this._xmlRootAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();        
    }


    public new void Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
    {
        // Out-of-the-box implementation.
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlTextWriter.Indentation = 2;

        // Call the shadowed version. 
        this.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, o, namespaces, null, null);
    }


    public new void Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
    {
        // Lookup the xml namespace and prefix to apply.
        XmlQualifiedName[] xmlNamespaces = namespaces.ToArray();                                
        XmlQualifiedName xmlRootNamespace =
            xmlNamespaces
                .Where(ns => ns.Namespace == this._xmlRootAttribute.Namespace)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        // Write the prefixed root element with its xml namespace declaration.
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement(xmlRootNamespace.Name, this._xmlRootAttribute.ElementName, xmlRootNamespace.Namespace);            

        // Write the xml namespaces; duplicates will be taken care of automatically.
        foreach (XmlQualifiedName xmlNamespace in xmlNamespaces)
        {
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", xmlNamespace.Name , null, xmlNamespace.Namespace);
        }

        // Write the actual object xml.
        ((IXmlSerializable)o).WriteXml(xmlWriter);

        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```c#
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "my", null, "MyNamespace");
    writer.WriteElementString("firstName", FirstName);
    writer.WriteElementString("lastName", LastName);
}
```

Comment: It will create <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<person xmlns:My="MyNamespace" xmlns="MyNamespace">
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</person> but not <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<My:person xmlns:My="MyNamespace">
    <My:firstName>John</My:firstName>
    <My:lastName>Doe</My:lastName>
</My:person>

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `XmlSerializer`? If not, try following code:

**Person.cs**

Add new method:

```
public void Serialize(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("My", "Person", "MyNamespace");
    writer.WriteElementString("My", "FirstName", "MyNamespace", FirstName);
    writer.WriteElementString("My", "LastName", "MyNamespace", LastName);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
person.Serialize(new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out));
```

Comment: Yes, I need XmlSerializer, this is only an example, but my object is more complex and contains nested properties, which are IXmlSerializable too.